# Teste unitário de uma função fetch javascript com jest ou mocha

Tags: javascript, testes-de-unidade, tdd, jest, mocha

Estou iniciando estudos com TDD e me deparei com uma função como essa:

```
const fetchexample = callback => {
  fetch('/token', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: 'user=teste'
  }).then(res => res.json()).then(json => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', json.access_token)
  }).then(() => callback())
}
```

Porém a minha dúvida é como exerceríamos o teste dessa função? Já que ela faz uma requisição assíncrona e nunca trabalhei com esse tipo de teste para esse tipo de requisição? Alguém teria algum exemplo sobre o assunto ou artigo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `it` recebe dois argumentos. A descrição e a função para executar o teste. Essa função pode passar um argumento, que é uma função a executar quando o teste terminar. Ficaria assim:

```
const fetchexample = callback => {
  fetch('/token', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: 'user=teste'
  }).then(res => res.json()).then(json => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', json.access_token)
  }).then(() => callback())
}
it('should test async code', function(done){
  fetchexample(done);
});
```

Outra maneira de fazer que a API também disponibiliza é retornar uma promise. mas neste caso já que é uma função callback que queres testar o `done` é mais prático.

Docs do Jest sobre testes assíncronos: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio basicamente fiz isso que você me falou. Também adicionei uma lib para me ajudar simulando o fetch assim eu poderia testar a função real.

Comment: @Edmo ótimo! O Jest é uma biblioteca muito boa, fico contente de ter ajudado.

Comment: @Edmo se a resposta resolveu o teu problema pode marcar como aceite